# Odata controller does not filter correctly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

```
public IHttpActionResult GetCompanyViewModels(ODataQueryOptions<CompanyViewModel> queryOptions)
        {
            IQueryable<CompanyViewModel> result = companiesService.GetCompanies();
            queryOptions.ApplyTo(result);
            return Ok<IEnumerable<CompanyViewModel>>(result);          
        }
```

i have this code.I try and do a

localhost:63447/odata/CompanyViewModels?$top=1

and the filtered is not applied at all.I get all the companies.

I do not understand why.

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.query.odataqueryoptions.applyto%28v=vs.118%29.aspx#M:System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo%28System.Linq.IQueryable%29), `ApplyTo` does not change current `IQueryable`, but returns a new `IQueryable` with query options applied. Therefore you should do this:

```
result = queryOptions.ApplyTo(result);
```